# Customising label appearance RadioGroup in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, radio-group

I am using material-ui RadioGroup. Individual labels are dynamically assigned. In the parent component I am setting width='50px'.
The problem is when label is way long over 50px the whole component width stretches. I would like to prevent this and truncate or clip the label and provide the tooltip with the full label value. How do I do that in the following code?:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
  },
  icon: {
    borderRadius: '50%',
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
    boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(16,22,26,.2), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(16,22,26,.1)',
    backgroundColor: '#f5f8fa',
    backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(180deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.8),hsla(0,0%,100%,0))',
    '$root.Mui-focusVisible &': {
      outline: '2px auto rgba(19,124,189,.6)',
      outlineOffset: 2,
    },
    'input:hover ~ &': {
      backgroundColor: '#ebf1f5',
    },
    'input:disabled ~ &': {
      boxShadow: 'none',
      background: 'rgba(206,217,224,.5)',
    },
  },
  checkedIcon: {
    backgroundColor: '#137cbd',
    backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(180deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1),hsla(0,0%,100%,0))',
    '&:before': {
      display: 'block',
      width: 16,
      height: 16,
      backgroundImage: 'radial-gradient(#fff,#fff 28%,transparent 32%)',
      content: '""',
    },
    'input:hover ~ &': {
      backgroundColor: '#106ba3',
    },
  },
});

// Inspired by blueprintjs
function StyledRadio(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Radio
      className={classes.root}
      disableRipple
      color="default"
      checkedIcon={<span className={clsx(classes.icon, classes.checkedIcon)} />}
      icon={<span className={classes.icon} />}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

export default function CustomizedRadios(props) {
  
    const onChange = (event) => {
      console.log(event.target.value)
        props.onChange(event.target.value)
    }
    
  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend"></FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup defaultValue={props.currentBookmark} aria-label="gender" name="customized-radios" onChange={onChange}>
          {props.bookmarkList.map(function (bookmark, index)  {return (<FormControlLabel key={index} value={bookmark.name} checked={(bookmark.name == props.currentBookmark)? true:false} editable={1} control={<StyledRadio />} label={bookmark.name} /> )})}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After  playing around while waiting for suggestions I came up with this approach.
I applied style formatting directly on component - to crop the text I used overflow property and white-space "nowrap". Additionally by using Tooltip I am maintaining visibility of full label when hovering over radio. Here is a piece of code:

```
return (
    <FormControl style={{"float": 'left'}} component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel style={{"float": 'left'}} component="legend"></FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup style={{"float": 'left'}} defaultValue={props.currentBookmark} aria-label="gender" name="customized-radios" onChange={onChange}>
          {props.bookmarkList.map(function (bookmark, index)  {return (<Tooltip title={bookmark.name} placement="left"><FormControlLabel key={index} value={bookmark.name} checked={(bookmark.name == props.currentBookmark)? true:false} editable={1} style={{ "font-family": 'Calibri, sans-serif', "white-space": 'nowrap', float: "left", width:'90px', paddingLeft: "6px", paddingBottom:"0px",paddingTop:"0px", border: "0px", marginBottom: "0px", overflow:'crop'}} control={<StyledRadio />} label={<span style={{"font-family": 'Calibri, sans-serif'}}>{bookmark.name}</span>} /></Tooltip> )})}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
```